# Get Total CPU # via WMI or T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, coldfusion, wmi, cpu-usage, perfmon

I don't want the list of all process, just a total percentage like you would see in windows taskmanager.

I will be using this information via coldfusion, but i am having all kinds of problems just trying to find a total number of current cpu usage.

I don't care if it comes from wmi or t-sql, i just want a total number for which i will be using to populate a gauge chart that via ajax will be showing my current cpu usage percentage...

Thank You...

Comment: http://crosenblum.pastebin.com/sTjwsmck

This is how i query the wmi via that wmi cfc query function:

<cfparam name="cpu_usage" default=0>

<!--- create object to call wmi function --->
<cfset obj_wmi = CreateObject( "component" , "wmi" ).init() />

<cfset cpu_obj = obj_wmi.execQuery( "Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor" ) />

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen( cpu_obj )#" index="d">
 <cfif cpu_obj[d].name eq "_Total">
  <cfset cpu_usage = cpu_obj[d].PercentPrivilegedTime />
 </cfif>
</cfloop>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394317(VS.85).aspx) WMI class to get this information. In your query you would use `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor.Name='_Total'`. See the article [ColdFusion and WMI](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=7F5B4) for more information on using WMI as well as the sample vbscirpt code in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Which counter should I use to get the total cpu usage, similar to the taskmanager? PercentUserTime, or PercentPrivaledgedTime etc.

Comment: If you want total cpu usage then you will need PercentProcessorTime and TimeStamp_Sys100NS. There is sample code in the second article that shows how to use these values to calculate the percentage, albiet in VBscript.

Comment: The values i get back grom TimeSpan_Sys100NS is always blank or empty. So that formula does not work. Would I need to adjust this at all for use on Vista?

Comment: What does your query look like? Can you update your post with the query you are using?

Comment: I just updated my post, to show the code, it kind of looks ugly. 

you can see the function i use at http://crosenblum.pastebin.com/sTjwsmck which is how any wmi query get's executed, and then returns it's results. Which in simpler terms, i hand it the name of a wmi object, then i have to loop thru all results to get the 1 result i need lol.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with cold fusion, but can you change the query to `obj_wmi.execQuery( "Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor.Name='_Total'" )` or

`select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor where name = '_Total'`. You can also try running the vbscript sample on Vista to see if it works.

Comment: No i can not, unless i change the cfc, to accept parameter's. So far it only accept's names of objects. Then i have to loop around results to just the result I want.

Comment: Where i try it with .name = or where name = i get no data returning back. I am open to suggestions..

Answer (score 2):

If it were me I would setup a perfmon counter on the machine in question to measure total CPU. This can be configured to write to a CSV file every couple of seconds.

You can then either have a task that writes that file to the database every minute and get CF to read that data so you can see a graph over time. Or, if you need the most recent value then just get CF to read the CSV file's last value and use that for your gauge.

Personally I store all the data in the database for all our web servers so I can see performance over time and run reports on busy or problem periods. Works great for us.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This someone else's answer, but in T-SQL, you could use this:

```
  DECLARE @ts_now BIGINT
    SELECT @ts_now = cpu_ticks / CONVERT(FLOAT, ms_ticks) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info

    SELECT top 1 record_id,
            DATEADD(ms, -1 * (@ts_now - [timestamp]), GETDATE()) AS EventTime, 
            SQLProcessUtilization,
            SystemIdle,
            100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS OtherProcessUtilization,
            100 - SystemIdle AS TotalCPU
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                    record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id,
                    record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') AS SystemIdle,
                    record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 'int') AS SQLProcessUtilization,
                    TIMESTAMP
            FROM (
                    SELECT TIMESTAMP, CONVERT(XML, record) AS record 
                    FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers 
                    WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'
                    AND record LIKE '% %') AS x
            ) AS y 
    ORDER BY record_id DESC
```