# Change the intervals of records registered by sys.dm_os_ring_buffers?

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the current CPU percentage that is shown in the task manager, I found this query in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534868/get-total-cpu-via-wmi-or-t-sql) that gives the total CPU usage which is what I want

**Query:**

```
    SELECT @ts_now = cpu_ticks / CONVERT(FLOAT, ms_ticks) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info

    SELECT top 30 record_id,
            DATEADD(ms, -1 * (@ts_now - [timestamp]), GETDATE()) AS EventTime, 
            SQLProcessUtilization,
            SystemIdle,
            100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS OtherProcessUtilization,
            100 - SystemIdle AS TotalCPU
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                    record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id,
                    record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') AS SystemIdle,
                    record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 'int') AS SQLProcessUtilization,
                    TIMESTAMP
            FROM (
                    SELECT TIMESTAMP, CONVERT(XML, record) AS record 
                    FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers 
                    WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'
                    AND record LIKE '% %') AS x
            ) AS y 
    ORDER BY record_id DESC
```

**Output:**
[image]

The problem is that this only refreshes every minute, and I need the current CPU when the query is executed. Is there a way to change the interval of the records that are generated? If not could I trigger a new record or another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an instantaneous value for CPU utilization from DMV that exposes the raw performance counter data. Note that since the perf counters are raw here, you have to perform either sampling or calculation based on the [performance counter type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancedata.countertype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_PerformanceData_CounterType_RawFraction32).

EG:

```
select  100.* c.cntr_value /  base.cntr_value cpu_usage_percentage
from sys.dm_os_performance_counters c
join sys.dm_os_performance_counters base
  on c.object_name = base.object_name
 and c.instance_name = base.instance_name 
where c.counter_name = 'CPU usage %'
and base.counter_name = 'CPU usage % base'
and c.object_name = 'SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats'
and c.instance_name = 'default'
```